# Linking borders of geometric figures

Tags: android, algorithm, geometry, figure

I'm creating an Android app which simulates petri nets. I'm representing place by circle and transition by square and I'm connecting those views by arc (it's just the name from petri nets for my purpose it's just a straight line) and here's the problem I'm facing, I know how to connect the centre point of those views but i don't know how to connect the border of circle and border of square, look at the image it should explain everything: [image]

In my app I know if I'm pointing a place (circle) or transition (square), I also know the dimension of those views and it's coordinates, can you suggest me any start point for writing an algorithm which will connect borders of those two shapes and draw the arrow at the end of the line? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a rule for what point on the border of the shapes to use?

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you mean by "rule" but  I don't know coordinates of the border point I need to count it

Comment: Do you want to choose the points on the borders of the two shapes through which a line connecting the center of the two shapes would pass? Or the bottom most point on the border of the upper shape and the upmost point on the border of the lower shape? Or some other rule?

Comment: First rule you suggested, the line which connects the center of two shapes but is started and ended on borders of shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a method that takes in an angle and returns the point on the boundary at that angle from the center. This involves a little trigonometry, and cases for the square. To draw a line between the boundaries of two shapes, determine the angle of the difference vector atan2(difference in ys, difference in xs). Choose the point on the boundary with that angle. (This chooses the point that is on the line segment connecting the centers. You can change this if you want.) Connect the two points you get with a line, and add the arrow's head.